# Why Selectize Dropdown Not Opening When Clicked Inside the Focused

Tags: drop-down-menu, selectize.js

```
$('#select-state').selectize({
            closeAfterSelect: true,
            onItemAdd: function() {
            this.close();
 }
 });
```

This is the multiple select dropdown, When selected, it closes the dropdown but after that if I clicked the focused dropdown dropdown is not opening. To work, I have to unfocus by clicking outside and when I click again the dropdown, then the dropdown is opening. I want a soultion for opening dropdown when we click the focused dropdown.

```
<select id="select-state" name="state[]" multiple class="demo-default" style="width:50%" placeholder="Select a state...">
                    <option value="">Select a state...</option>
                    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                    <option value="CA" selected>California</option>
                    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

It took me a long time to figure this out, so I'll post my answer here almost 2.5 years later for posterity :)

```
$('#select-state').selectize({
  closeAfterSelect: true,
  openOnFocus: false,

  //Close dropdown on clicking on control in focus
  onInitialize: function () {
    var that = this;
    this.$control.on('mousedown', function () {
      if (that.isOpen)
        that.close();
      else
        that.open();
    });
  },
});
```

I am Not using the `closeAfterSelect: true` part as that's not in my requirement, so you will have to account for the dropdown re-opening when deleting items from the list.

If I find a fix for that, then I'll edit this.  I hope this is still useful to someone!

Answer (score 0):

This does not solve your whole problem, since the focused select's menu still won't show on click. But you can call `blur()` in the `onItemAdd` callback, making the - now - blurred input clickable again.

Also, you don't need to call this.close(), the library will do that for you.

```
$('#select-state').selectize({
  closeAfterSelect: true,
  onItemAdd: function(){
    this.blur();
  }
});
```